# The term 'Get-ADUser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell

I have used the following query to list the users in a windows 2008 server, but failed and got the below error.

```
$server='client-pc-1';$pwd= convertto-securestring 'password$' -asplaintext -
force;$cred=new-object  -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist 'Administrator',$pwd; invoke-command -computername $server -credential 
$cred -scriptblock {Get-ADUser -Filter (enabled -ne $true)}
```

The exception is given below...Can anyone help me to solve this?

```
The term 'Get-ADUser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct 
and try again.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-ADUser:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 158):

If the ActiveDirectory module is present add

```
import-module activedirectory
```

before your code.

To check if exist try:

```
get-module -listavailable
```

ActiveDirectory module is default present in windows server 2008 R2, install it in this way:

```
Import-Module ServerManager
Add-WindowsFeature RSAT-AD-PowerShell
```

For have it to work you need at least one DC in the domain as windows 2008 R2 and have Active Directory Web Services (ADWS) installed on it.

For Windows Server 2008 read [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/08/30/install-active-directory-management-service-for-easy-powershell-access.aspx) how to install it

Comment: np :) though I would change it to: get-module activedirectory -listavailable

Comment: @ShayLevy Yes it's better to check a specific module! My intention was to help user1805353 to know wich module can load.

Comment: I have Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 and no `activedirectory` module is present here.

Comment: I had to get the case correct for the import to work. 'get-module ActiveDirectory'

Comment: @bahrep You need to install it before: `Import-Module ServerManager` and `Add-WindowsFeature RSAT-AD-PowerShell`. At least one DC in the domains must be 2008 R2 and have `Active Directory Web Services (ADWS)` installed on it.

Answer (score 51):

Check [[here]](https://4sysops.com/wiki/how-to-install-the-powershell-active-directory-module/#windows-8-windows-81-windows-10) for how to add the activedirectory module if not there by default. This can be done on any machine and then it will allow you to access your active directory "domain control" server.

## EDIT

[Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520)

[Windows 7 (Dead - 5/4/23)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887)

In essence, you need to download and install [Remote Server Administration Tools. After installing do the following steps:

- Open Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn On/Off Windows Features
- Find "Remote Server Administration Tools" and expand it
- Find "Role Administration Tools" and expand it
- Find "AD DS And AD LDS Tools" and expand it
- Check the box next to "Active Directory Module For Windows PowerShell".
- Click OK and allow Windows to install the feature

Windows server editions should already be OK but if not you need to download and install the [Active Directory Management Gateway Service](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=2852). If any of these links should stop working, you should still be able search for the KB article or download names and find them.

Comment: @StevePettifer: would be better if you edit the answer

Comment: @jay Fair point. Think I was in a rush and that gave me the answer I needed but was being brain dead about it. Edited the answer and removed the comment now.

Comment: The 1st link is dead. I found instructions at: https://4sysops.com/wiki/how-to-install-the-powershell-active-directory-module/#windows-8-windows-81-windows-10

Comment: In my case (win10, enterprise edition)  -- Installation  of "Remote Server Administration Tools (KB958830)."  was the only step needed. I restarted machine for good measure (probably not needed)

Comment: Thanks @RobMosher - I updated the first link. I See the second link is also broken, but I don't have time to fix that now. Good find on the first one!

Answer (score 16):

```
get-windowsfeature | where name -like RSAT-AD-PowerShell | Install-WindowsFeature
```

(BTW, `get-windowsfeature` is part of ServerManager module which is **available only on Windows Server**.)

Comment: Blindly installing wildcard search results seems like a terrible idea.....

Comment: `The term 'Get-WindowsFeature' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`

Answer (score 11):

For the particular case of Windows 10 October 2018 Update or later `activedirectory` module is not available unless the optional feature `RSAT: Active Directory Domain Services and Lightweight Directory Services Tools` is installed (instructions [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520) + uncollapse install instructions).

Reopen Windows Powershell and `import-module activedirectory` will work as expected.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't see the Active Directory, it's because you did not install AD LS Users and Computer Feature.  Go to Manage - Add Roles & Features.  Within Add Roles and Features Wizard, on Features tab, select Remote Server Administration Tools, select - Role Admininistration Tools - Select AD DS and DF LDS Tools.

After that, you can see the PS Active Directory package.

Answer (score 7):

Open Turn On/Off Windows Features.

Make sure you have Active Directory Domain Services selected. If not, install it.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

For Windows 11 (and maybe Windows 10), you can execute the below command in powershell

```
Get-WindowsCapability -Online | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*ActiveDirectory.DS-LDS*"} | Add-WindowsCapability -Online
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using windows 10 and encounter this error, you can solve this error message by installing RSAT (Remote Server Administration Tools).

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520

Comment: This worked for me using Win10 21H2

Answer (score 0):

As @HO-LI-Pin said you need to install the [RSAT Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520). You can do this also easily direct in PowerShell:

```
Install-WindowsFeature RSAT-AD-PowerShell
```