# Check if the user is a member of a list of AD groups

Tags: powershell, active-directory, quest

```
$groups = 'group1', 'group2'....
```

I need to check if the user is in a specific AD group and echo the group name if he is not ; can I do it in the pipeline?

I have googled a lot and cannot find anything, maybe I am too bad at Google search in English :).

```
$groups |
    Get-QADGroupMember |
    Get-QADUser -SamAccountName 'lalala' | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.SamAccountName -ne $null) {
            Write-Host "ok"
        } else {
            Write-Host 'not ok'
        }
    }
```

How can I display: `not ok. user is not in`*`group_name`*?

Comment: You have a list of groups. Which of them is the user supposed to be a member of? Any? All? A specific one? None? Also, I'd recommend starting from the other end: get the groups the user is a member of, then check if the list contains the relevant group.

Comment: Just a counter question here, in an ideal scenario a group generally contains more members than a single user does. So that being said wouldn't it be faster to get each user's groups & check if he is member of certain group than going the other way around? Just asking... :)

Answer (score 6):

The question is why do you want to use the pipeline when just looping through the results is so easy?

To check if a user is a member of a list of groups:

```
$user = "TestUsername"
$groups = 'Domain Users', 'Domain Admins'

foreach ($group in $groups) {
    $members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Recursive | Select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName

    If ($members -contains $user) {
        Write-Host "$user is a member of $group"
    } Else {
        Write-Host "$user is not a member of $group"
    }
}
```

And for multiple users:

*Seems this question gets a lot of views, so I've updated my answer to resolve the obvious problem of the original version. This isn't a model answer and isn't the most efficient, but it accomplishes the goal.*

```
$users = "TestUsername1", "TestUsername2", "TestUsername3"
$groups = 'Domain Users', 'Domain Admins'

foreach ($group in $groups) {
    $members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Recursive | Select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName

    foreach ($user in $users) {
        If ($members -contains $user) {
            Write-Host "$user is a member of $group"
        } Else {
            Write-Host "$user is not a member of $group"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting th errror `The term 'Get-ADGroupMember' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet`. What module do I need to import for this to work? -edit- Found the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/17548616/602585

Comment: @PSaR Whilst your edit was constructive, it would be better suited as a separate answer. This is an old answer of mine and I'd not do it this way anymore either as it's not that efficient.

Comment: This seems like a lot of unnecessary queries for Get-ADGroupMember - you're pulling all the members of all the groups every time you move to a new username, which in theory could have thousands of person objects in. If you looped through groups first, then checked if they contained the user, you would dramatically increase performance and decrease run time.

Answer (score 0):

If your server doesn't have the Active Directory PowerShell feature installed on it, you can use this method. Here I'm checking if a domain group is part of the local administrators group on the server, but you can just change the `GroupPrincipal` to `UserPrincipal` and supply the username if you want to check if a user belongs to a group. Also, if the group is a domain group, then use the `$domainContext` for both `FindByIdentity` calls.

```
function Test-DomainGroupIsMemberOfLocalAdministrators([string] $domainName, [string] $domainGroupName)
{
    Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement'
    $domainContext = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext]::new([System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Domain, $domainName)
    $localMachineContext = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext]::new([System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Machine)
    $domainGroup = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal]::FindByIdentity($domainContext, $domainGroupName)
    $localAdministratorsGroup = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal]::FindByIdentity($localMachineContext, "Administrators")

    if($domainGroup -ne $null)
    {
        if ($domainGroup.IsMemberOf($localAdministratorsGroup))
        {
            return $true
        }
    }
    return $false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is @henrycarteruk answer truely the best way to acomplish that? Let's have an example:
I have list of 50 groups and I want to check if user is a member of each group.

By this example:

- I have to get list of members for each groups
- I have to check if each list contains my user login
- Write answer

Problems I see:

- group can have many, many users
- I can have many, many groups I want to check if user is member of

I did fast test:

1. My user have 180 groups
2. I want to check if he's member of 10 groups
   I took my ~20 seconds

My approche is below.

Have a list of groups you want to check, but you need whole DN of group.

```
$list = 'CN=Administrators,CN=Builtin,DC=Fabrikam,DC=com','CN=Administrators,CN=Builtin,DC=Fabrikam,DC=com','CN=Administrators,CN=Builtin,DC=Fabrikam,DC=com'
```

Get user groups:

```
$user_groups = (Get-ADUser $login -Properties memberof | Select-Object memberof).memberof
```

Check which groups user have:

```
foreach($group2 in $list){
        if($user_groups.Contains($group2)){
            Write-Host "$login is member of $group2"
        }else{
           Write-Host "$login is not a member of $group2"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers provided can work for the task at hand but are not giving the most effective method which is actually **letting [LDAP](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx) do its job** instead of having PowerShell perform the filtering.

```bash
$groupsFilter = ''
# assuming we have the Group's SamAccountName
# create a filter clause for each group
'group1', 'group2', '...' | ForEach-Object {
   $groupsFilter += '(samAccountName={0})' -f $_
}

# We need the user's DistinguishedName
# to perform the Member Attribute filtering
$userDN = (Get-ADUser theUser).DistinguishedName

$filter = -join @(
   '(&'                          # AND, all conditions must be met
      '(!member={0})' -f $userDN # The user is NOT a member
      '(|'                       # OR, any of the conditions must be met
         $groupsFilter           # Follow with the filter for any of the groups
      ')'                        # Close OR clause
   ')'                           # Close AND clause
)

# Now with the constructed filter we can search for any group
# which's samAccountName is one of those in the array of Groups
# AND the target user IS NOT a Member of
Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter $filter
```

If we are looking to find those groups where the user is not a *recursive member*, in the words, where the user **is not a member of the group OR any nested group**, we only need to change the `(!member=...)` clause to use a **LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN**:

```bash
'(!member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={0})' -f $userDN # The user is NOT a recursive member
```

To have a reference, the constructed LDAP Filter would look like this:

```
(&
   (!member=CN=someuser,OU=someOU,DC=someDomain)
   (|
      (samAccountName=group1)
      (samAccountName=group2)
      (samAccountName=group3)
   )
)
```